# Rescue NameError but not NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, nameerror, nomethoderror, rescue

I need to catch a NameError in a special case. But I don't want to catch all SubClasses of NameError. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
# This shall be catched
begin
  String::NotExistend.new
rescue NameError
  puts 'Will do something with this error'
end

# This shall not be catched
begin
  # Will raise a NoMethodError but I don't want this Error to be catched
  String.myattribute = 'value'
rescue NameError
  puts 'Should never be called'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-raise exception if its class is different than a given:

```
begin
  # your code goes here
rescue NameError => exception
  # note that `exception.kind_of?` will not work as expected here
  raise unless exception.class.eql?(NameError)

  # handle `NameError` exception here
end
```

Comment: This solution fits my needs.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it in a more traditional way

```
begin
  # your code goes here
rescue NoMethodError
  raise
rescue NameError
  puts 'Will do something with this error'
end
```

Comment: It will work only with `NoMethodError` and not with other subclasses now or in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the exception message and decide what to do.
Here is an example using the code you provided.

```
# This shall be catched
begin
  String::NotExistend.new
rescue NameError => e 
  if e.message['String::NotExistend'] 
     puts 'Will do something with this error'
   else 
    raise
  end
end

# This shall not be catched
begin
  # Will raise a NoMethodError but I don't want this Error to be catched
  String.myattribute = 'value'
  rescue NameError => e 
  if e.message['String::NotExistend'] 
     puts 'Should never be called'
  else
    raise
  end
end
```

Comment: And what if there will be `String::NotExistend2`? It is better to check against exception's class instead as answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38931436/1941418

Comment: I guess it depends on what all your "special" cases are.  The point of my answer was that you can use the message to filter out very specific info on a particular exception.  If just checking the class covers all your special cases than use that,  if not you have other options available